# Idle Session in aix

Tags: aix

where in AIX is timeot set for a telnet session?
I need to keep each session open indefinitely.
I check the following files
/etc/security/login.cfg
/etc/security/.profile
/etc/profile and my login files
either TMOUT=0 or i remove it form these files, but idle session still went out?
there is any services to start and stop for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See this [Tek-Tip forum post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1394610&page=47) for the same issue.

In short:

- check your TMOUT and TIMEOUT environment variables, if set, they could initiate closing of idle sessions
- check /etc/security/login.cfg for a shell timeout in "logintimeout"
- check your firewall, if it drops idle tcp connections after some time

Maybe you could also configure your clients to send null-packages from time to time to keep sessions alive.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) is a more general solution to this problem.